# How to add SynchronizationCallbacks to @TransactionalEventListener during spring boot application startup?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that uses a few `@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)`. I noticed that spring boot doesn't do any exception logging for them when they end up with an exception being thrown.

Because of this I wanted to add some generic logging facility for such exceptions. I found that `TransactionalApplicationListener.SynchronizationCallback` is the interface I need to implement. However it seems complicated to register these callbacks. I didn't find any call of `TransactionalApplicationListener#addCallback` in the spring dependencies that would achieve this.

Trying to get a list of `TransactionalApplicationListener` and the `SynchronizationCallback` injected and then call `addCallback` in a `@PostConstruct` didn't get me further because there were always no listeners injected even though the application did make successful use of them.

So how do I add `SynchronizationCallback`s to `TransactionalApplicationListener`s during spring boot application startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `TransactionalApplicationListener`s like all `ApplicationListener` are not beans in the spring context. They live somewhat outside of it (see `org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext#addApplicationListener`). So injecting them is not possible for the application context.

While debugging and looking through spring sources one finds that these listeners are being created by `org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListenerFactory`. And that is where my solution steps into. We decorate that factory with another one that is aware of `SynchronizationCallback`s:

```
public class SynchronizationCallbackAwareFactory implements EventListenerFactory, Ordered {

    private final TransactionalEventListenerFactory delegate;
    private final Provider<List<SynchronizationCallback>> synchronizationCallbacks;
    private final int order;

    public SynchronizationCallbackAwareFactory(TransactionalEventListenerFactory transactionalEventListenerFactory,
                                               Provider<List<SynchronizationCallback>> synchronizationCallbacks,
                                               int order) {
        this.delegate = transactionalEventListenerFactory;
        this.synchronizationCallbacks = synchronizationCallbacks;
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsMethod(Method method) {
        return delegate.supportsMethod(method);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener<?> createApplicationListener(String beanName, Class<?> type, Method method) {
        ApplicationListener<?> applicationListener = delegate.createApplicationListener(beanName, type, method);
        if (applicationListener instanceof TransactionalApplicationListener) {
            TransactionalApplicationListener<?> listener = (TransactionalApplicationListener<?>) applicationListener;
            Collection<SynchronizationCallback> callbacks = this.synchronizationCallbacks.get();
            callbacks.forEach(listener::addCallback);
        }
        return applicationListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

Note that I use a `javax.inject.Provider` in my case to make the retrieval of the callbacks at the latest possible time.

The decorator has to be `Ordered` because spring will use the first factory supporting the method it gets across. And therefore the order of an instance of this class has to have higher precedence as the order value `50` of `TransactionEventListenerFactory`.

Comment: But do you also know why the error handling is not working in case of the listeners? I am facing the same issue, maybe using multicaster and its error handler would solve the issue?

Comment: @Mejmo I'm not sure what you are exactly talking about. I don't see an error handler here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationEventMulticaster.html

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.html

Comment: @Mejmo You can try out using the error handler. Seems like a possible solution. I didn't know about that before. But you have to check if this really works for after commit transaction listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problem with code as below

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class SomeListenerFacade {
    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void onSomething(SomeEvent event) {
        throw new RuntimeException("some cause");
    }
}
```

I followed your solution. It worked. On the way I've found an alternative way for at least seeing that exception in the logfile

```
# application.properties

logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils = DEBUG
```